# Pushing value from text input to search widget in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, search, widget

I am developing a surveying app that among other things, asks the user for their address/closest street intersection, and then later asks them add features around they're "neighborhood".

I would like the value they enter in the address text input to be pushed to the search widget onblur of the address input to avoid entering the same info twice.

I've tried just setting the value of the search widget form text to the text input value, and it changes the text visually but when I hit the search button it says "please enter a search term"

Anyone have any ideas on this, does what I'm asking even make sense?

Answer (score 1):

How are you setting the value of the search widget? You need to do it like this:

```
searchWidget.set('value', [your value]);
```

Here's a JSFiddle illustrating it working: https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/cutdfhj5/

Comment: Something like this? http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/search_customized/